# How to solve Device Detection 404 Not Found error in Sitecore 9.0.2?

Tags: upgrade, device-detection

I'm currently working on a Sitecore upgrade for my company but have found that the device detection is causing huge slow down. Disabling the device detection speeds things right along but while watching the traffic when it is in use it appears to get `404` errors making it's initial request to the services.

[image: Sitecore Device Detection Screenshot]

I thought it would be from maybe a proxy issue but even trying on a device that is off the network I'm not able to get a response. I can however ping these URLs are get an IP address. No packages make it but it appears to be a valid address.

[image: Sitecore Device Detection Ping]

Any assistance to what may be going on here would be fantastic! I'll be opening a ticket shortly with Sitecore to see if they can't help resolve and will post back if I find anything.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: And all of these steps are followed?  Firewall openings etc?  https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/device_detection/device_detection/configure_sitecore_device_detection

Comment: Would the firewall still be an issue even on a personal computer?

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a proxy from my web.config solved the issue. Traffic sent through the proxy got access to the database service and the device cache was formed. Was able to see devices in Sitecore analytics afterwards.

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy>
  <proxy
    usesystemdefault="true"
    proxyaddress="http://YOURPROXYHERE"
    bypassonlocal="true"
  />
  <bypasslist>
    <add address="[a-z]+\.YOURLOCALDOMAINHERE\.com$" />
  </bypasslist>
</defaultProxy>
```

Sorry for the self answer but should help anyone who's running behind a proxy.